# How to tranform a hana::tuple_t with an arbitrary type meta-function?

Tags: c++, boost-hana

Lets say I have two types each having an internal type:

```
struct A1{
    using type = int;
};
struct B1{
    using type = double;
};
```

I created a `hana::tuple_t` from my classes (e.g. `auto Types = hana::tuple_t<A1, B1>`) and I would like to get a similar `hana::tuple_t` of the internal types of my class (e.g. `hana::tuple_t<A1::type, B1::type>`)

I wanted to use the transform function to get the resulting tuple_t:

```
auto result = hana::transform(Types, [](auto t){return t::type;});
```

I get the compile error :

```
error: ‘t’ is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
```

What is the correct way to achieve this using `hana::tranform`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hana::template_`

```
template<typename O>
using inner_type = typename O::type;
auto result = hana::transform(Types, hana::template_<inner_type>);
```

`tuple_t` produces a `tuple`, which cannot contain *types*. Instead it contains `hana::type`s, which are *values* that *represent* types. `template_` turns a type-level function (a `template` type alias or class) into a value-level "metafunction". If you want to use an explicit lambda for the `transform`, you can, but it gets gory:

```
auto result = hana::transform(Types, [](auto t) { return hana::type_c<typename decltype(t)::type::type>; })
```

The type of `t` in the lambda is `hana::type<T>` for some `T`, so `decltype(t)` unwraps that type from the value, the first `::type` gets `T`, the second `::type` gets your target type, and the `type_c` wraps it all back up.